# Zend or Apache redirection case issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, case-sensitive

I am playing with Zend on my Windows 10 computer.  I have a "localhost" website with Apache installed on my C: drive.  I am not using Zend framework.

To educate myself, I have tried to build a mini-framework here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /moulding/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The website I am building is called "moulding".  If I browse to "localhost://moulding/", I get a "Not Found The requested URL /moulding/ was not found on this server." error.

If I browse to "localhost://Moulding/" or "localhost/mOulding/" etc, I can see my site.

I have used Edge, IE, FF & Chrome with the same results.

I have copied, and renamed the site folder various things (editing the .htaccess to suit), and everything works correctly, either proper, lower or mixed case.

Is moulding a reserved word or something?

Comment: Do you have a folder called 'moulding' by any chance? And what do you mean by "playing with Zend" if you are not using the framework? Zend is the name of a company.

Comment: I installed Zend server with Apache

Comment: I installed Zend server with Apache.  Yes, the folder the application is inside, is called moulding